# Will a 2nd degree function always have maximum 2 roots?

Tags: functions, roots

Will a function of 2nd degree always have maximum 2 roots?

For example: $$f(x) =  x^2 - ln(x^2 +1) -1 $$

EDIT: More specific; if you have a function with $$k * x^2$$ where k is a real number, and this term is only added or subtracted to the function, not multiplied with any other term, does the function have maximum 2 roots?

Comment: Would you call $f(x)=\sin (x^2)$ a second degree function?

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that your terminology ("2nd degree function") is not standard at all. Practically nobody would call $\ln(x^2)$ a "second degree" function. The "degree" applies almost exclusively to polynomials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> More specific; if you have a function with $$k * x^2$$ where k is a real number, and this term is only added or subtracted to the function, not multiplied with any other term, does the function have maximum 2 roots?

No, take as an example $\sin x+0.01 x^2$, it has $6$ roots. Reducing the coefficient of the $x^2$ term will significantly increase the number of solutions. For instance, here is a plot of $\sin x+0.00001x^2$, see if you can count how many times it crosses the $x$-axis:

$\hspace{5mm}$ [image]

Comment: I count 201. =)

Comment: @corsiKa You're off by 1, it's 202. ;-)

Comment: How can it be even? `sin(0) = 0`, and the function should have the same number of roots on either side of the y axis. So `2k + 1` has to be odd, right?

Comment: @corsiKa Not necessarily.

Comment: Don't leave me hangin' bro. You can't just drop a "that fundamental truth you think you know, it's not right" and then casually walk away! How is `2k + 1` not odd?!

Comment: @corsiKa I didn't say that $2k+1$ wasn't odd (for $k\in\Bbb Z$), my comment was about the way you thought about it. Where your reasoning fails is that the function isn't odd, so it isn't symmetric around the $y$-axis: $$\sin(-x)+0.00001(-x)^2=-\sin x+0.00001x^2\neq-(\sin x+0.00001x^2).$$ You don't notice this change since the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is small enough to "hide" it.

Comment: Ohhh... I honestly thought that was an artifact of the image rendering, so I didn't count it since it wasn't on the positive side. Interesting! Haha but I'm not crazy, `2k + 1` is totally odd! *phew*

Comment: @corsiKa Indeed! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 4):

Yes. And no.

A second order polynomial $p:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, i.e. a real function defined as

$$p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$$
where $a,b,c$ are real numbers, has a maximum of $2$ roots as it can have either $1$ root ($x^2$), $2$ roots ($x^2-1$) or $0$ roots ($x^2+1$).

A second order polynomial $p:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, i.e. a complex function defined as

$$p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$$
where $a,b,c$ are complex numbers, has $2$ roots or one double root.

In general, a function $f(x)$ in which $x^2$ appears may have as many roots as you want it to have. See $\sin(x^2)$ from the commentary in the example.